# Hx-push-url doesn’t work on back button click

Tags: django, htmx

I am trying to integrate Htmx with django and achieve single page application behaviour. I am rewritting Djangoproject.com poll app with htmx. When I click on detail page link, content loads, htmx push a new url in address bar. When I press back button, it took me to index page perfectly for the first time, after that if I again go to detail page and click back button, url shows of the index, button index content doesn’t load, content remains same as detail page.
Here is my code

```
views.py

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    if request.headers.get("Hx-Request") is not None:
        return render(request, 'main/index/index.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'main/index/index-full.html', context)
    
    
def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    print(request.headers.get("Hx-Request"))
    if request.headers.get("Hx-Request") is not None:
        return render(request, 'main/detail/detail.html', {'question': question})
    else:
        return render(request, 'main/detail/detail-full.html', {'question': question})
```

```
index.html

<div id="index" class="">

    {% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><div class="has-text-link" hx-get="{% url 'main:detail' question.id %}" hx-push-url="true" hx-target="#index" hx-swap="outerHTML">{{ question.question_text }}</div></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
    <p>
        No polls are available.
    </p>
    {% endif %}

</div>

index-full.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% include 'main/index/index.html' %}
{% endblock content %}
```

```
detail.html

<div id="detail" class="">

    <form action="{% url 'main:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset>
            <legend><h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1></legend>
            {% if error_message %}<p>
                <strong>{{ error_message }}</strong>
            </p>
            {% endif %}
            {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
            <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
            <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
            {% endfor %}
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Vote">
    </form>

</div>


detail-full.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% include 'main/detail/detail.html %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I found no error in browser console, no error in terminal

Now, I know I can put a back button in detail page that can took me to index page. But user won't use that, they will just use the back button on their device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this javascript code you can reload the page when the user click the back button:

```
var auxBack = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");

if (auxBack[0].type === "back_forward") {
    location.reload(true);
}
```

Comment: Doesn’t work. I am on android with Opera browser

Comment: Is there any Htmx or Django solution?  I mean without Javascript

Comment: Now I see, if press back or forward button in the browser it works, it doesn’t work in device back button. However this is okay. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I face this problem in my Django application after a lot of searching I found the solution for this in the HTMX documentation by assigning the hx-history-elt
you can lock it at [hx-history-elt](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-history-elt/) and it works for me grate